# Check innerHTML for a scraped table and modify variable based on that array entry

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, web-scraping, html-table

I am trying to check the table entry for a webscrape for the 'color' element in the innerhtml and then change the variable for "bonus" based on which of the table entries have this value.

I can post the innerHTML version and see it there but I can't not seem to get the script to recognize it is there.

```
let checkCrimes = {
    "check": function() {
        if (user.stamina < 690) {
          let randomTimer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300 + 900);
          checkCrimes.queue(randomTimer);
        } else if ($(gameDocument).find('#crimebubble').length) {
          let crimeCooldown = $(gameDocument).find("#crimebubble>.countdown").eq(0).text().split(":");
          crimeCooldown = crimeCooldown.map((x, i) => {
            if (i === 0) {
              return Number(x) * 60;
            } else {
              return Number(x);
            }
          });
          crimeCooldown = crimeCooldown.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
          checkCrimes.queue(crimeCooldown);
        } else if ($(gameDocument).find('#form_crimes').length) {
          let lastPostTime = localStorage.getItem('lastPostTime') || 0;
          if ($(gameDocument).find('#form_crimes input[type="radio"]').length > 10) {
            // Handle other cases or skip if necessary
          } else {
            let crimeList = [];
            $(gameDocument).find('#form_crimes tbody tr').each(function() {
              const crimeData = $(this).find('td').toArray().map(x => x.innerHTML);

              if (crimeData.includes('--')) {
                return; // Exclude entries with "--" from the list
              }
              const bonus = "testfailed";
              if (crime.Data[3].includes('color')) {
                bonus = "Stealth"
              }
              if (crime.Data[2].includes('color')) {
                bonus = "Defense"
              }
              if (crime.Data[1].includes('color')) {
                bonus = "Offense"
              }


              const trimmedCrimeData = [crimeData[1], crimeData[2], crimeData[3], crimeData[6], bonus];

              crimeList.push(trimmedCrimeData);

            });
```

I have also tried just checking the entire crimeData array for the entry just to check and it didn't work either. But this is effectively what I want to do in this function: scrape the crime table, check which one has the bonus, push text only to the trimedCrimeData

here is the HTML I am working with if it helps

```
18%, 50%, <span style="color:#00B910;font-size:11px;">37%</span>, <span class="wartooltip" style="margin:0px;"><span style="color:lime;">strong</span><span class="wartooltiptext">Strength indicated how strong the crime is, strong is good and weak is bad!</span></span>, off
    66%, 9%, <span style="color:#00B910;font-size:11px;">30%</span>, <span class="wartooltip" style="margin:0px;"><span style="color:grey;">normal</span><span class="wartooltiptext">Strength indicated how strong the crime is, strong is good and weak is bad!</span></span>, off
    10%, 44%, <span style="color:#00B910;font-size:11px;">51%</span>, <span class="wartooltip" style="margin:0px;"><span style="color:lime;">strong</span><span class="wartooltiptext">Strength indicated how strong the crime is, strong is good and weak is bad!</span></span>, off
```

Comment: What problem are you having? Please post a [mre]

Comment: I am unable to get the script to recognize the color in the attached HTML. The script scrapes the table from a webpage would it help if I instead put the scraped data into an array to give an example?

Comment: Where is `<tr>` and `<td>` in the HTML?